# Parametric solution of a Diophantine equation of three variables

Tags: number-theory, diophantine-equations, parametrization

I came across this Diophantine equation $$4x^2+y^4=z^2$$
Primitive solutions of this equation can be found by
\begin{align}
\begin{split}
x&=2ab(a^2+b^2)\\
y&=a^2-b^2\\
z&=a^4+6a^2b^2+b^4\\
\end{split}
\end{align}
where $a$, $b$ are relatively prime and $1 \leq b < a$. One of these two, one is odd, and the other one is even.

I would like to know the intermediate steps that are required to find such a parametrization. I tried to manipulate the identity.
$$4x^2+y^4=z^2 \implies 4x^2=(z+y^2)(z-y^2)$$ and then using parity check to further simplify it.
Another approach was
$$4x^2+y^4=z^2 \implies 4xy^2=(2x+y^2+z)(2x+y^2-z)$$
I could not make any more progress. Some help will be appreciated.

Comment: I would try using the fact that $2x,y^2,z$ is a Pythagorean triple https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As [JCAA](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/796779/jcaa)'s question [comment](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3749475/parametric-solution-of-a-diophantine-equation-of-three-variables#comment7710920_3749475) suggests, rewriting the equation as $(2x)^2 + (y^2)^2 = z^2$ shows $2x$, $y^2$ and $z$ form a [Pythagorean triple](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pythagorean_triple). Primitive solutions are obtained from

$$2x = 2mn \implies x = mn \tag{1}\label{eq1A}$$

$$y^2 = m^2 - n^2 \implies y^2 + n^2 = m^2 \tag{2}\label{eq2A}$$

$$z = m^2 + n^2 \tag{3}\label{eq3A}$$

where $m$, $n$ are relatively prime and $1 \leq n < m$.

Note \eqref{eq2A} shows $y$, $n$ and $m$ form another Pythagorean triple. In this case, it's another primitive solution since $\gcd(m,n) = 1$ means $y$ is also relatively prime to $m$ and $n$. Also, since $y$ is odd (due to $2x$ being even in the original equation), you get

$$y = a^2 - b^2 \tag{4}\label{eq4A}$$

$$n = 2ab \tag{5}\label{eq5A}$$

$$m = a^2 + b^2 \tag{6}\label{eq6A}$$

where $a$, $b$ are relatively prime and $1 \leq b < a$. Plugging \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A} into \eqref{eq1A} gives

$$x = 2ab(a^2 + b^2) \tag{7}\label{eq7A}$$

while plugging \eqref{eq5A} and \eqref{eq6A} into \eqref{eq3A} gives

$$\begin{equation}\begin{aligned}
z & = (a^2 + b^2)^2 + (2ab)^2 \\
& = a^4 + 2a^2b^2 + b^4 + 4a^2b^2 \\
& = a^4 + 6a^2b^2 + b^4
\end{aligned}\end{equation}\tag{8}\label{eq8A}$$

Comment: Nice solution :) A very quick one too. After less than $10$ views. Is it possible to generalize this idea? Say $(kx)^2+y^4=z^2$. Probably yes. Thanks for the solution.

Comment: I was trying to solve for $k=3$ using your method. It is indeed not straightforward for odd $k$. Some work needs to be done. For odd $k$ we shall most probably get more than one parametric solutions. For $k=3$, there seemed to be two families of solutions.

Comment: @user156896 With your generalization of $(kx)^2 + y^4 = z^2$, if $kx$ is even, then $kx = 2mn = 4ab(a^2 + b^2)$. I mistakenly stated for even $k$ you get $x = kab(a^2 + b^2)$ in my now deleted previous comment. Since $k \mid 4ab(a^2 + b^2)$, for $a$ or $b$ is even, then with $k = 2, 4, 8$, there are no extra restrictions on $a$ and $b$, but otherwise they're more limited. If $k$ is odd, you have a choice of which term is even, so there could be at least $2$ families of solutions. If $y^2$ is even, then $y^2 = 2mn$ & $kx = m^2 - n^2$, which as you state with $k = 3$, is not so straightforward.